# How set property background "Transparent" in listbox

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml

I have ListBox and i need set background "Transparent".

[image]

I've selected in red, then that should be transparent:
[image]

style ListBox, ListBoxItem, ScrollViewer and ScrollBar:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="5" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFF0F0F0" Fill="#FFEFEFEF"/>
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="DecreaseRepeat" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearRepeatButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowUp" Height="6" Width="10" Data="F1 M 541.537,173.589L 531.107,173.589L 536.322,167.49L 541.537,173.589 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.7,0.75" StartPoint="0.25,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#CC000000" Offset="0.25"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0.75"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </RepeatButton>

                    <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track" Orientation="Vertical" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource NuclearThumbStyle}"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"/>
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"/>
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>

                    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" x:Name="IncreaseRepeat" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearRepeatButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowDown" Grid.Row="4" Height="6" Width="10" Data="F1 M 531.107,321.943L 541.537,321.943L 536.322,328.042L 531.107,321.943 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.4,1" StartPoint="-0.3,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#CC000000" Offset="0.25"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0.75"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#33000000" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">

                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="GridRoot">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>

                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" TargetName="DecreaseRepeat"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" TargetName="IncreaseRepeat"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" TargetName="PageDown"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" TargetName="PageUp"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"/>

                    <ScrollBar Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"   Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                    <ScrollBar Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"   Orientation="Vertical" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<!---->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
<Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Orientation="Horizontal"  Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle1}" Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="VerticalScrollBarBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
<GradientStop Color="#E1E1E1" Offset="0"/>
<GradientStop Color="#EDEDED" Offset="0.20"/>
<GradientStop Color="#EDEDED" Offset="0.80"/>
<GradientStop Color="#E3E3E3" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarDisabledBackground" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome x:Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="{TemplateBinding Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="VerticalScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome x:Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsDragging}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="{TemplateBinding Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
<GradientStop Color="#E1E1E1" Offset="0"/>
<GradientStop Color="#EDEDED" Offset="0.20"/>
<GradientStop Color="#EDEDED" Offset="0.80"/>
<GradientStop Color="#E3E3E3" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
<Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="UpArrow" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"/>
                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}"/>
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarPageButton}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="VerticalGripper"/>
                    </Track.Thumb>
                </Track>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="2" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="DownArrow" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledBackground}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="LeftArrow" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}" Background="#FFEB0707"/>
                        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarButton}" Grid.Column="2" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="RightArrow" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!---->






<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource btnPressStroke2}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OutsideFontColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ScrollViewer Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}"  Margin="1"   Focusable="false" Background="Transparent">
                            <WrapPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True"  />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OutsideFontColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.73"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientOver" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOn">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.84"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.1000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOff">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4000000" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientOver" Fill="{StaticResource hoverGradient}" Stroke="{StaticResource hoverStroke}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelectedDisabled" Fill="{StaticResource grayGradient}" Stroke="#7F8E8F8F" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradientSelected" Fill="{StaticResource BtnOverFill}" Stroke="{StaticResource selectedStroke}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundHighlight" Margin="1" Stroke="#A0FFFFFF" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="contentPresenter"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOff}" x:Name="SelectedOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOn}" x:Name="SelectedOn_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BackgroundGradientSelected" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2" StrokeThickness="1" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ListBox in XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="list_category" Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  >
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Header="Сопровождающие" Width="300"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="GroupBox" Background="Transparent">
                <DockPanel Tag="{Binding id_Person}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding surname}" Padding="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Padding="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastname}" Padding="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding quarter}" x:Name="quarter" Padding="5" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding halfyear}" x:Name="halfyear" Padding="5" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding year}" x:Name="year" Padding="5" Grid.Column="4"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />

                                    <TextBlock Text="Период: " Padding="5" Grid.Column="1"    HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />

                                    <TextBlock Text="Квартал" Padding="5" Grid.Column="2"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Полгода" Padding="5" Grid.Column="3"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Год" Padding="5" Grid.Column="4"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Цена: " Padding="5" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#FFB51414" />
                                </Grid>


                                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinHeight="180" MaxHeight="180">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding photo}"/>
                                </Grid> 
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="send_mess" Tag="{Binding id_Person}" Click="send_mess_Click" Content="Написать сопровождающему"/>
                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding id_Person}" >
                        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="combobox_term">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Квартал" Tag="1"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Полгода" Tag="2"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="Год" Tag="3" IsSelected="True"/>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding id_Person, Converter={StaticResource CheckBoxToCheked}}" Content="Выбрать" />
                    </DockPanel>

                </DockPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you want the item background color to be transparent? or both the item and listbox background

Comment: no, items should not be transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your control template, you have a statement saying

```
<Border ... Background="#FFFFFFFF">...
```

Since that doesnt inherrit the background of the style, you are hardcoding the background for your Listbox.

Try changing that to `Background={TemplateBinding Background}`

N.B.

Its in the default style for ListBox... The complete statement is

```
<Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2"> 
    <ScrollViewer Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}"  Margin="1"   Focusable="false" Background="Transparent"> 
         <WrapPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True"  /> 
    </ScrollViewer> 
</Border>
```

Comment: It just does not default style

Comment: Edited answer I think the problem lies in your default style

Comment: tip top =) very well =) Thanks